# How i can find a specific row and look for the minimum element index in a numpy array

Tags: python

I got a numpy array from a csv file. It is 6 X 6. I want to find a specific row and then find the lower element index.

Comment: take a look here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html

Comment: Hi sir! I try it, but always came with the number of the row not the element.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a random array 6x6, since you did not provide any data and finds the index of the minimum in the `row_n` specific row.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(6, 6)
print(a)

row_n = 0
print(a[row_n, :].argmin())
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, the index was inside a array. Sorry for that!

Comment: Happy I could help, but wdym the index is inside an array ?